# Working with arrays in go, cannot compile code due to mismatched types

Tags: go

So I'm trying to compile the forllowing code in go, which I just picked up a few hours ago

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    a := [...]float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    sum := avg(a)
    fmt.Println(sum)

}

func avg(arr []float64) (sum float64) {
    for _, v := range arr {
        sum += v
    }
    sum = sum / float64(len(arr))
    return
}
```

I get an error saying that I can't pass the 10 element long array because the function was defined with a []float64 array. Is there a way around this or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define `a` as array of length and in `avg` you expect a slice of `float64`

If you dont need fixed length define `a` as slice:

```
a := []float64{...}
```

Or you can convert `array` to slice:

```
sum := avg(a[:])
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing arrays and slices:

```
a := [...]float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} // Array of type [10]float64
a := []float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} // Slice of type []float64
```

Just remove the ... and your code will work

Answer (score 0):

`[10]float64` and `[]float64` are distinct types in Go. Your `avg` function expects a slice of type `float64` but you are instead passing it an array of type `[10]float64`. As others have noted, you can either get rid of the `...` in your declaration of `a` or you can pass `a[:]` to your `avg` function.